# Why anonymous user needs right "Feeds_ViewFeed" to publish a package by an authenticated user?

Tags: proget

I'm not able to publish a package for an authenticated user by using the `username:password` as an API key, as long the anonymous user does not have at least the "Feeds_ViewFeed" right.

But I don't want to have my packages visible for anonymous users. But I need to publish packages by an authenticated user.

Tested with the following configuration

- ProGet is hosted by the windows service
- Anonymous has no rights assigned

If I try to push a package I get the following error:

```
Pushing xxx to 'xxx'...
Please provide credentials for: xxx UserName:
Cannot prompt for input in non-interactive mode.
```

Tried as well to give the anonymous user the "Feeds_AddPackage" right and protect the feed by an API key. Doesn't work either without the "Feeds_ViewFeed" assigned to anonymous. As soon as "Feeds_ViewFeed" is assigned pushing with an API key works as well.

Is this by design, configuration error or a bug?

Any advice?

Product: ProGet
Version: 3.5.5

Comment: From what I can see, there is no path that requires the Feed_ViewFeed privilege in the upload operation, so I'm guessing NuGet.exe is sending another request before the PUT request that actually does require the Feed_ViewFeed privilege, e.g. a `list` command or something similar. Can you check a [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) trace of the requests sent by the NuGet client to verify this?

Comment: Looks like the first thing NuGet does is trying to read the feed.

http://pastebin.com/EakEfs86

And this fails as the Feeds_ViewFeed is not given

Comment: Getting the same issue